# Conditional PDO Delete statement probably not working

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, pdo

The portion that is trying to delete duplicate entries in the database seems incorrect. So I suppose I am asking what would be the correct way to do that in this example. I am not totally new to PHP , but this is beyond me. If you could please tell me what is wrong and how to fix that would be greatly appreciated.

Now on to what I am trying to accomplish. I have a multidimensional array filled with values that is generated by a function. What I am trying to do is if there is a value in the array that already exists in the database delete it. Code:
enter code here

```
if(is_array($items)){

$values = array();  

foreach($items as $row => $value){

    $rsn = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $value[0]);
    $rank = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $value[1]);
    $values[] = "('', '$rsn', '$rank', '')";  

    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE rsn = :rsn";

    $query = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $query->execute(array(":rsn" => $value[0]));

    $results = $query->rowCount();

    while($deleted = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = :id";

        $query = $conn->prepare($sql);

        foreach($deleted as $delete){

        $query->execute(array(':id' => $delete));

        }

    }

}

//user_exists_delete($conn, $rsn);

$sql = "INSERT INTO users(id, rsn, rank, points) VALUES ";

$sql .= implode(', ', $values);


if(!empty($rank)&& !empty($rsn)){

    if(mysqli_query($connect, $sql)){

        echo "success";

    }else{

        die(mysqli_error($connect));

    }

}
```

}

EDIT: I have got it partially working now, just need it to delete all dupes instead of only one. I edited code to reflect changes.

Comment: Don't mix `mysqli_` and `PDO`, just use `PDO`. If you bind you don't have to escape.

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that the reason I am using two different extensions is because I don't know how to do the mysqli parts in pdo. I tried earlier and it didn't execute

Comment: `PDO` automatically cleanses input to prevent SQLi, you don't need to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` or anything like that, the `execute()` and `bindParam()` methods do that for you.

Comment: _"probably not working"_ and _"I think I made a mistake and am doing something wrong."_ are _not_ clear problem statements. First, find out _if_ the code works or not. If it doesn't, then you need to let us know the expected result and what actually happens. If it _does_ work but you just want someone to look the code over, you should post it on Code Review.

Comment: Could you please post the structure of `$items`? Without knowing how to traverse that array for the IDs, it's not possible to provide a solution.

Comment: Your `foreach()` loop inside the `while()` is strange, but not knowing what data may be there it's hard to say for certain. I imagine you can just use the `execute()` (no loop) but use the `$row['id']` as the parameter so: `$query->execute(array(":id" => $row['id']));`

Comment: $items is the multidimensional array that I was talking about earlier. It consists of name, rank, xp, kills. Id is coming from the while loop. And I thought that the foreach loop would have to be inside while in order to get all the results instead of one and still have access to the $row['id]

Comment: Also you have `foreach($items as $row => $value){` then in the `while()` you name it `$row` again: `while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){` which will overwrite that variable.

Comment: If I were you, I would create a couple functions (or a class/method) that compartmentalizes a bit so you could do like `userExists($id)` and `deleteUser($id)`, stuff like that. How you have it is 1) hard to follow 2) hard to troubleshoot

Comment: The foreach loop, the one that is $row as $rows is all the id's that match the SELECT statement

Comment: After the `while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){` do `print_r($row);` to make sure you are certain you are iterating over what you think.

Comment: I already did, it is iterating over the ids that match where the select statement is finding duplicate entries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple problems, if you didn't strip much of your original code and if you don't need to do more than just what you shown why not just send a delete instruction to your database instead of checking validity first?

You have

```
//Retrieve ID according to rsn.
$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE rsn = :rsn ";
//Then retrieve rsn using rsn??? Useless
$sql = "SELECT rsn FROM users WHERE rsn = :rsn ";
//Then delete using ID, retrieved by rsn.
$sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = :id";
```

All those could simply be done with a delete using rsn...

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE rsn = :rsn";
```

The row won't be deleted if there are no rows to delete, you don't need to check in advance. If you need to do stuff after, then you might need to fetch information before, but if not, you can use that while still checking the affected rows to see if something got deleted.

Now, we could even simplify the script by using only one query instead of one per user... We could get all rsn in an array and then pass it to the DELETE.

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE rsn in :rsn";
//Sorry not exactly sure how to do that in PDO, been a while.
```

Comment: Dont you have to check if you only want the delete query to delete dups? But I agree to many select statements

Comment: If you wanted to delete dupes only then yes, you would have to count how many dupes, and limit the delete according to that amount, to make sure there is one remaining. But this was not highlighted at all in your question. And IMO, best way to delete dupes is to not create them first :)

Comment: In my database the rsn row is set to unique to stop dupes. The delete statement is so the insert statement keeps going with no duplicate key error.

Comment: Would spaces be problem anywhere?

Comment: You can use INSERT IGNORE if you want no error on the insertion of duplicate keys. Also, you could use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE to create an update from your insert if it was to insert a dupe... Read those up on mysql docs.

Comment: Salketer answer is the right answer for this scenario

Comment: If so, you can mark it as such if your problem's fixed. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it I just omitted the WHERE clause in the delete statement so all records are being deleted before that insert gets ran again.

Comment: I really doubt that it is even close to be an answer to your problem... You'd loose everything, each time you add a new user...